# How to add scripts to spec file using pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

lets say `a = Analysis(['x.py', 'y.py'],...)`

I want to write a script to add .py files to `a` in spec file so that when I run a script by providing some `x.py` the spec file has to be updated like this.

`a = Analysis(['x.py', 'y.py', 'z.py'],...)`

Is there any command/script to add py scripts to analysis class in spec file? I have already build spec file with some py scripts. If in case I have to add additional scripts how can I do that without editing spec file

How can I accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear how your question isn't covered by http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html You'll need to tell us via an [edit] what your specific problem is, and how you tried to solve it, and how the official docs don't help you.

Comment: My question is: Is there any command/script to add py scripts to analysis class in spec file?

I have already build spec file with some py scripts. If in case I have to add additional scripts how can I do that without editing spec file

Comment: You should [edit] your question so these details are there for everyone to see. Comments can be removed. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

From http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files it would appear you are looking for "glob abbreviations".

If you have a common naming convention for the files to be included, or have them in a separate directory, you can use the methods shown in the examples on the site to add your files.

From the above link, this has a single file, a directory, and a wildcard match.

```
added_files = [
     ( 'src/README.txt', '.' )
     ( '/mygame/data', 'data' ),
     ( '/mygame/sfx/*.mp3', 'sfx' ),
     ]
```

If, from your example, you wanted to include all .py files, you could do something along the lines of:

```
a = Analysis(
      datas = [
           ( '*.py', '.' ),
           ])
```